# Best practice: New consumer in Kafka needs the latest state of all historical messages

Tags: apache-kafka

Let's assume this scenario:

- Each time a customer is added/updated/deleted, a message with the current state is published in a specific ("entity") topic.
- There are several consumers updating their own databases and keeping their customer data up-to-date.
- After some years, a new consumer is added.
- This new consumer needs all customers with their latest state in its database.

By listening to new messages (maybe some retention time back), the new consumer only gets the new/updated customers, but not the old ones.

What is the best practice to solve such a scenario? Do we need to trigger the producer to produce a message for all customers again (reprocess all messages)? Should we setup the new consumer's database outside Kafka? Are there other solutions?

Comment: Unclear what "database" you're referring to, but this is exactly the use case for Kafka Streams KTables

Comment: @OneCricketeer This database is just an example (a consumer keeping track of data in an own way). Thanks a lot! I will take a look at it as well. Is it best practice to go with Ktables or log compaction?

Comment: A KTable is built on top of a compacted "statestore" topic, by default, and this can be stored persistently on disk in RocksDB. https://kafka.apache.org/32/documentation/streams/core-concepts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should look into Kafka [log compaction](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#compaction).
When enabled, instead of deleting old data Kafka will keep the last known value for each message key.
New consumers can then start from the beginning of the topic.

Comment: Exactly what I meant. Thanks a lot!